# Q&A: Does solidity have any structures besides mapping and arrays?

Tags: ethereum-classic

**This part of own Q&A serial of posts which shares knowledge gained during work on one project**

I faced with very limited options to express my thoughts and intents on solidity which is partly because of lack basics structures that are available in others top trend languages. Is there any options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t found any reference on Sets or HashMaps, but here is [a collection of structures implemented by community](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity) via smart contracts.